# Mapping Redux reducers to unknown keys in State

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, ecmascript-5

According to the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html), normalizing state is the best way to approach data structures on the front end. The example they give is below:

```
{
  posts : {
    byId : {
        "post1" : {
            id : "post1",
            author : "user1",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]    
        },
        "post2" : {
            id : "post2",
            author : "user2",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]    
        }
    },
    allIds : ["post1", "post2"]
  },
  comments : {
    byId : {
        "comment1" : {
            id : "comment1",
            author : "user2",
            comment : ".....",
        },
        "comment2" : {
            id : "comment2",
            author : "user3",
            comment : ".....",
        },
        "comment5" : {
            id : "comment5",
            author : "user3",
            comment : ".....",
        },
    },
    allIds : ["comment1", "comment2", "comment5"]
  }
}
```

How would one go about writing reducers in such a way that the id of the post or comments can be dynamically set as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure (because the question is not very clear), but I think you want to use computed property names when returning a new object literal from the reducer:

```
projectsReducers (state={}, action) {
    // Ensure that the projectName is actually accessible
    if (!action || !action.projectName) {
        return state;
    }

    // Retrieve the project name dynamically
    const projectName = action.projectName;

    return {
        // Preserve the previous state by spreading all of it's properties
        // please note that Object spread is still a Stage 3 proposal for ECMAScript,
        // so transpilation might be required
        ...state,

        // Assign current project's new state
        [projectName]: singleProjectReducer(
            state[projectName],
            action
        )
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What happens if state is initialising and there are no actions being dispatched? Would I do something like check if it exists, if it doesn't then return an empty object rather than further reducers?

Comment: Then you don't want to execute this code. You have to put some sort of safeguard like ``if (!action || !action.projectName) { return state; }``. I've modified my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll give it a shot and let you know how I get on. I also made my question a little clearer. Is that better? do you have any suggestions on what might need to be made clearer?

Comment: You are using some sort of weird syntax - I can only assume it's more of a pseudo-code rather than JavaScript.

Comment: yeah its just pseudo code...sorry I didnt realise it made the code unclear...I wondered why I got a downvote in 10 secs.

Comment: Probably because someone did not understand your code. Always make sure to write your questions as clear as possible, even if it requires a ton of code to be copy-pasted.